# Substitui um valor fixo no CASE por um SELECT e um JOIN?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

```
SELECT
DISTINCT P.CD_PACIENTE
, P.NM_PACIENTE
, DECODE (P.TP_SEXO, 'M', 'MASCULINO',
                     'F', 'FEMININO', 
                     'I', 'INDEFINIDO') SEXO                         
, TRUNC(P.DT_NASCIMENTO) DT_NASCIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (P.DT_NASCIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) IDADE_PACIENTE
, A.CD_ATENDIMENTO
, A.DT_ATENDIMENTO
, (SELECT FN_IDADE (A.DT_ATENDIMENTO, 'a A / m M / d D' ) FROM DUAL) DIAS_INTERNADO
, PE.CD_PRESTADOR --PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, PE.NM_PRESTADOR
, L.CD_LEITO --LEITO DO PACIENTE
, L.DS_LEITO
, UI.CD_UNID_INT                             CD_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO--UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO VINCULADA A INTERNAÇÃO
, UI.DS_UNID_INT                             UNIDADE_INTERNACAO
, (SELECT S.NM_SETOR FROM SETOR S WHERE UI.CD_SETOR = S.CD_SETOR) AS SETOR_UNIDADE_INTERNACAO --SETOR DA UNIDADE DE INTERNAÇÃO    
, E.CD_ESPECIALID                            CD_ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO--ESPECIALIDADE VINCULADA AO MÉDICO PRESTADOR DO ATENDIMENTO
, E.DS_ESPECIALID                            ESPEC_ATENDIMENTO
, (CASE WHEN UI.CD_UNID_INT = 63 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (64, 60, 82) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) STATUS   
FROM LEITO L
JOIN ATENDIME A     ON A.CD_LEITO         = L.CD_LEITO
JOIN UNID_INT UI    ON UI.CD_UNID_INT     = L.CD_UNID_INT
JOIN SETOR S        ON S.CD_SETOR         = UI.CD_SETOR
JOIN PACIENTE P     ON P.CD_PACIENTE      = A.CD_PACIENTE    
JOIN ESP_MED EM     ON EM.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR --ESPECIALIDADE DO ATENDIMENTO
JOIN ESPECIALID E   ON E.CD_ESPECIALID    = A.CD_ESPECIALID --SE COLOCAR P.CD_PRESTADOR IRÁ RETORNAR MAIS RESULTADOS, POIS UM PRESTADOR PODE TER MAIS DE UMA ESPECIALIDADE.
JOIN PRESTADOR PE   ON PE.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR       
WHERE A.TP_ATENDIMENTO = 'I'
AND A.CD_MOT_ALT IS NULL
```

Gostaria de saber se eu consigo ao invés dessa operação do no case: `UI.CD_UNID_INT = 63 OR E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (64, 60, 82)`

Substitui-la por algum select com join para eu não engessar o código e toda fez que for alterado especialidade ou setor ter que alterar o código?

Ao invés de fazer isso: (CASE WHEN (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 63 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (64, 60, 82))  OR (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 64 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (800, 652, 802)) OR (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 68 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (800, 652, 802)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) STATUS

Answer (score 1):

Isso que você quer é possível, sim; inclusive você já se faz uma [*subconsulta*](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php).

```
SELECT
DISTINCT P.CD_PACIENTE
-- demais campos
, (CASE WHEN UI.CD_UNID_INT = (SELECT MAX(S_2.CODIGO) from SETOR S_2 where S_2.DESCRICAO = 'TESTE_SETOR') AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (SELECT FROM ESPECIALID E_2 WHERE E_2.DESCRICAO LIKE '%TESTE_ESPECIALIDADE%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) STATUS
FROM LEITO L
JOIN ATENDIME A     ON A.CD_LEITO         = L.CD_LEITO
JOIN UNID_INT UI    ON UI.CD_UNID_INT     = L.CD_UNID_INT
JOIN SETOR S        ON S.CD_SETOR         = UI.CD_SETOR
JOIN PACIENTE P     ON P.CD_PACIENTE      = A.CD_PACIENTE    
JOIN ESP_MED EM     ON EM.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR --ESPECIALIDADE DO ATENDIMENTO
JOIN ESPECIALID E   ON E.CD_ESPECIALID    = A.CD_ESPECIALID --SE COLOCAR P.CD_PRESTADOR IRÁ RETORNAR MAIS RESULTADOS, POIS UM PRESTADOR PODE TER MAIS DE UMA ESPECIALIDADE.
JOIN PRESTADOR PE   ON PE.CD_PRESTADOR    = A.CD_PRESTADOR       
WHERE A.TP_ATENDIMENTO = 'I'
AND A.CD_MOT_ALT IS NULL
```

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim (atente para as validações do *subselect*, quais as colunas que você precisa validar/trazer).

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender, ou talvez não expressei melhor. Esse ai foi um exemplo, mas eu terei que fazer com vários códigos de unidade de internação se relacionando com determinados códigos de especialidade eu teria que fazer isso na realidade. (CASE WHEN (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 63 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (64, 60, 82))  OR (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 64 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (800, 652, 802)) OR (UI.CD_UNID_INT = 68 AND E.CD_ESPECIALID IN (800, 652, 802)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) STATUS

Comment: Editei o comentário

Comment: Linhares, acabei de descobrir que sua resposta me ajudaria se eu tivesse essa relação, mas não tenho, eu não tenho relação da especialidade com a unidade de internação, ele é vinculada de acordo com o que o usuário informa, sem restrições, não existe um relacionamento entre as tabelas... Mas obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Respondendo minha pergunta, não tem como ser feito esse select.

Não existe relação da especialidade com a unidade de internação, ele é vinculada de acordo com o que o usuário informa, sem restrições, não existe um relacionamento entre as tabelas.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta só evidencia que o problema na pergunta não poderia ser reproduzido, ninguém além de você poderia saber as relações das entidades.

Comment: Exatamente, quando eu percebi que a relação não existia, publiquei que de fato minha pergunta não tinha solução.